# Read list items as string in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have such lines in the code that reads values from excel file

```
df = pd.read_excel('Data.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
mylist = df['Numbers'].tolist()
```

I got a list of numbers like that `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100]`
How to convert the numbers in that list to string?

Comment: Amazing. That's exactly what I was searching for. Please post it as an answer so as to give a rep for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the pandas series object using [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html?highlight=astype#pandas.Series.astype) method which accepts `numpy.dtype` or Python type.

```
df['Numbers'].astype(str).tolist()
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the problem you're having is probably because `join`  connects elements inside a list of `strings` and not `integers` (which is what you have in that list). Therefore you can:

```
a = ''.join(map(str, my_list))         #1st way
b = ''.join(str(i) for i in my_list)   #2nd way

print(a), print(b)

12345100
12345100
```